# Can't load images when deploying nuxt3 app on netlify

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, production, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to deploy a nuxt3js app to netlify , the app is successfully deployed , but the pictures that I have inside my app can't load .

[image]

My images are located as below :
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error reproduction steps?

Comment: What is the actual code that you're using to load your images?

Comment: I'm loading the images like this : 
src="../../../assets/images/promotion(1).png"

but i guess i should do it like that :  src="~/assets/images/promotion(1).png"

what u think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up setting my images in the "Public" folder :)